# jdbcTemplate query only executes with SELECT *

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, jdbctemplate

Long time lurker and learner, first time question here.  I'm working a project for a local library to pull some data from their database to help the employees pull books put on hold for patrons.  The catch here is the access to the database is read only.  I cannot create any temporary tables or views.

We've created a long query to generate the data needed, I used a couple CTEs to whittle things down and then there's some logic based on which location the book may reside in to show where it should pick from.  All in all, we're happy with the query results.

When I try to implement it using jdbcTemplate, I can't seem to find a way to get anything other than SELECT * to work.

```
WITH holdCTE1 (holdID, itemID, ...) AS (
SELECT * 
FROM
    table 1, 
    table 2,
    table 3
WHERE
    yada yada
```

This will give me results if I then do a SELECT * FROM holdCTE1.

If instead I specify columns, like this

```
WITH holdCTE1 (holdID, itemID, ...) AS (
SELECT t1.holdID, t2.itemID, t3.title 
FROM
    table 1, 
    table 2,
    table 3
WHERE
    yada yada
```

I get a syntax error at the first from table, regardless.  I've tried adjusting all my table JOINs and using aliases and just about everything I can come across, but it doesn't seem to help.

A couple of things we're using to help the filtering and such, since we can't create a view to make it easy, is to call out the subqueries, so for example, in CTE1 we add a final column

```
'bib hold' AS hold_type
```

Even with the SELECT *, 'bib hold AS hold_type, I get the same syntax error.  The actual wording of the error is:

```
StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar ... then my query ... nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near ... the first thing under the FROM line
```

The library is using a Postgresql database, and I'm using Spring with jdbcTemplate for the SQL side.

Thanks in advance for looking.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the poorly worded question, but I think I stumbled across an answer this evening.  I was checking all of my queries I'd noted in pgAdmin, and I did a copy/paste into my java class.

With the escape characters, the code seems to run just fine.  So this looks like it is passing info correctly to the query

```
WITH hold_bib (hold_id, item_id, birl_bib, patron, status, hold_type) AS (SELECT\n"
        + "    h.id,\n"
        + "    i.record_id,\n"
        + "    birl.bib_record_id,\n"
        + "    h.patron_record_id,\n"
        + "    i.item_status_code,\n"
        + "    'bib'AS hold_type\n"
```

The function looks like this at the beginning now:

```
public List<Hold> libraryNotPicked() {
    String sql = "\n"
        + "WITH hold_bib (hold_id, item_id, birl_bib, patron, status, hold_type) AS (SELECT\n"
        + "    h.id,\n"
        + "    i.record_id,\n"
        + "    birl.bib_record_id,\n"
        + "    h.patron_record_id,\n"
        + "    i.item_status_code,\n"
        + "    'bib'AS hold_type\n"
         ...
        + " ;

List<Hold> holds = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(Hold.class));
    return holds;
```

Seems to me the key is the \n type characters in the query.